# WiFi modem requires PC to be on to work

Tags: wireless-networking

I can only use the Internet with my WiFi modem from my laptop or phone if the PC connected to the modem with a cable is on. If I trun the PC off, then my wireless devices cannot connect to the Internet through the modem.

Why is the modem’s Internet connection dependent on the PC and how can I stop it?

Comment: Actually my modem is not connecting to internet untill i configure it in my pc

Comment: What make and model is the modem?

Answer (score 0):

You could purchase an old standalone PC to act as the one you currently have. It would always be on, so the modem would stay connected.

If you want the modem only on sometimes, use Telnet, TeamViewer, SSH, or other remote connection tools that work over LAN. Then use your laptop to turn on the PC.

A dedicated wireless router would also help.

Comment: *>You could purchase an old standalone PC to act as the one you currently have. It would always be on, so the modem would stay connected.*   That is hardly feasible in the least. The issue is to decouple the modem from the PC, not replace the PC.